# Why Ajax request, using the GET method, cannot be cached in Opera?

Tags: ajax, caching, opera

Please look at this small test:

http://www.karapuz.by/media/js/ajax-GET-caching-test.html

It seems that Opera (mine is 10.10), in contrast to IE, FF, GC, and Safari, is not caching the ajax response, even if it is explicitly told to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, refreshing the page with F5 in Firefox has the same effect

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct, F5 should reload everything (both the page and ajax request) from the server.

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](http://stevesouders.com/tests/ajax_caching.php) you need to remove the expiration of your header.

Comment: Thanks, Knu. I tried to remove it--no changes, Opera still re-requests.

Additionally, I didn't understand why the expiration header must be removed, if it is a standard mean to control the client's cache.

Comment: you also have to remove the cache control // if it's working ull just have to serve opera something different using a filter like `opera && opera.toString()=="[object Opera]"`

Comment: Ok, I tried to remove both headers, but still Opera makes recurring requests. Again, why not to use cache headers? Is something wrong with them if I want to tell the client browser to use its cache?

As a workaround for Opera maybe I could use hidden iframes.

Comment: Did you clean the cache before?

Comment: It now seems that the problem is in the jQuery library. 

I made another test http://www.karapuz.by/media/js/ajax-GET-caching-test2.html , it uses more low level XHR object, not the 
jQuery's "ajax" as it was in the first test. And now Opera is fine!